# how to pass string from Angular to .NET Core WebAPI and get json in return?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

everybody!

I want to send string from my front side, I use Angular9. Here's code:

```
const word: string = this.str;
console.log(word);
this.http.post(this.myurl, word)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // console.log(this.value)
  });
```

Variable **word** contains string(word), which is sent by post request to the server. This.myurl is URL string, which consist of Server URL.
And my backend should receive and compute this(word) string. After that, it should return json string to front. Here's code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Adding([FromBody] string word)
    {
       
        string json = string.Empty;
       //some calculations with **word** after which I will get dictionary.
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
        
      //some calculations
        return json;
    }
```

So, the thing is, Angular reports 415 error in Console. I know how to make post request without subscribing, while I can't understand how to receive json in Angular in post request. Each time I get different json string from server (it actually depends on string you've sent from front), so, I can't construct static Model for this purpose.
Anyway, I will be really grateful, if you help me with this issue.

Comment: Just return the object, the framework will serialize it for you. That's the point. I believe from body is looking for a property called word in an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, you might have the same problem as me, here's solution:
First of all, thank you Dear **Aluan Haddad**, I followed your tip, so, I created Model in my Backend (Model.cs, which contains only one **string** property), then, I put object of this Model as argument for my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ModelWord>> Endings(Model model)
        {
//....
}
```

And as return value this method just redirect to GET controller with json data, and my front get data from Get method(controller).

In my Angular, I've created Model too, with one string.